# How do goblins work for a ranger's favored enemy?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger

PHB, p91:

> Choose a type of favored enemy: aberrations, beasts, celestials, constructs, dragons, elementals, fey, fiends, giants, monstrosities, oozes, plants, or undead. Alternatively, you can select two races of humanoid (such as gnolls and orcs) as favored enemies.

My ranger is familiar with goblinoids. Can I choose that as a single type? Can I choose it as one of two humanoid types? Or do I need to choose specific goblinoids, say goblins and hobgoblins?

Comment: As an aside, the [Revised Ranger](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_RevisedRanger.pdf) can take *all* humanoids as a favored enemy, which greatly simplifies this question by removing it entirely.

Answer (score 10):

### You can choose them as a humanoid race.

Goblinoids are considered a humanoid race. We can verify this by looking at their stat blocks in the Monster Manual.

> **Bugbear**
>
> Medium humanoid (goblinoid), chaotic evil *(MM, 33)*

Goblins themselves share the same trait.

> **Goblin**
>
> Small humanoid (goblinoid), neutral evil *(MM, 166)*

As a result, you can pick goblinoids as a race of humanoid, and then select a second humanoid race as well.

Comment: I think I agree with your answer, but the rules allow you to choose "a type" or "two races of humanoid."  Saying you can choose them as "a type of humanoid," while accurate, confused me at first and I had to read it a couple times to realize which part of the rule you were applying.

Comment: Fair enough, I've edited my answer to specify humanoid "race" rather than "type".

Comment: Goblinoid isn't a race, it's a tag. Bugbear and goblin is the race in your example.

Comment: Do you have a source that shows Goblinoid isn't a humanoid race? I find nothing that states they aren't, and don't see any other purpose for having them listed as "humanoid (goblinoid)" if they aren't a humanoid race.

Comment: Doval hits upon one of my questions - what leads you to believe that Goblinoid is a race, rather than Goblin, Hobgoblin, and Bugbear all being separate (humanoid) races?

Comment: Not trying to be rude, but I'm genuinely not sure where the confusion comes from. Orcs are listed as *humanoid (orc)*. Orc, Orc War Chief, Orc Eye of Gruumsh, and Orog are all listed as *humanoid (orc)*. Would you argue that those are not all orcs? No, of course not; they're listed as orcs. On the flip side, something like the Bullywug is listed as *humanoid (bullywug)*. The bullywug is its own unique type of humanoid. If a bugbear was not considered a "goblinoid" they would be listed as *humanoid (bugbear)*, but they aren't.

Comment: MM p. 7 defines "the races of goblinoids (goblins, hobgoblins, and bugbears)." "Goblinoid" is a tag for these 3 races, similar to how "shapechanger" is a tag for jackalweres and werewolves.

Comment: @Baron a tag can group creatures based on any arbitrary characteristic; it doesn't always indicate a race. The only thing creatures with the shapechanger tag have in common is that they have more than one form; vampires, lycanthropes, slaad, mimics, doppelgangers, yuan-ti and succubi aren't related to each other. An orog would still be an orc even if it didn't have the tag anyways; the Monster Manual tells you it is one.

Comment: Volo's guide also treats Bugbears, Goblins, and Hobgoblins as separate races (and gives stats for each). If they were all the same race they each would be considered a subarace under a single statistic heading. Goblinoid is a subcategory of humanoid.

Answer (score 10):

## Goblinoid isn't a race; it's a family of races.

Goblins, hobgoblins and bugbears are distinct humanoid races, each with their own physical characteristics and culture.

The word *goblinoid* in their stat blocks is a tag:

> A monster might have one or more tags appended to its type, in parentheses. For example, an orc has the humanoid (orc) type. The parenthetical tags provide additional categorization for certain creatures. The tags have no rules of their own, but something in the game, such as a magic item, might refer to them. For instance, a spear that is especially effective at fighting demons would work against any monster that has the demon tag.

Note that tags have no inherent meaning. While the goblinoid tag applies to creatures that are closely related to each other, other tags like *shapechanger* apply to a disparate collection of creatures, such as vampires, lycanthropes and doppelgangers.

The Monster Manual has separate sections for goblins, hobgoblins and bugbears. This is the first clue that they're not just one species. In their respective sections, we find these quotes:

> Goblins belong to a family of creatures called Goblinoids. Their larger cousins, hobgoblins and bugbears, like to bully goblins into submission.
>
> Hobgoblins belong to a family of creatures called Goblinoids. They are often found lording over their cousins, the smaller goblins and the ferocious bugbears.
>
> Bugbears are often found in the company of their cousins, hobgoblins and goblins.

Goblinoids are consistently referred to as a *family* of creatures and the different races are referred to as *cousins* of each other.

Volo's Guide to Monsters contains playable monster races; goblins, hobgoblins and bugbears are presented as distinct options. The book also goes into more detail about these races as a group and individually:

> In bygone times the goblinoids were distinct from one another, with separate faiths and different customs ... What the goblins, the bugbears, and the hobgoblins were before their gods bowed to Maglubiyet no longer matters. Now they are, first of all, followers of Maglubiyet ... Each race his its own tendencies, outlook, culture, and gods. But Maglubiyet's hand joins them together, just as he made all their gods parts within a greater whole.

The common thread between goblinoids is their shared worship of Maglubiyet.

Comment: This is the correct conclusion. Consider adding the quote from page 7 of the Monster Manual, in the Humanoids block: "the races of goblinoids (goblins, hobgoblins, and bugbears)"

Answer (score 0):

[Jeremy Crawford, D&D 5e rules designer, unofficially says they're separate races in this tweet](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/993374734002761728):

> *would love it if you could put this one to bed. Can Rangers choose ‘Goblinoid’ as one of their races in regards to Favored Enemy? Cheers*
>
> If you're choosing a type of humanoid for Favored Enemy, goblinoid is too broad, but goblin, hobgoblin, bugbear, or the like works.
>
> More about Favored Enemy. It tells you to pick a creature type, but if you pick humanoid, you choose two races of humanoid. Goblinoid isn't a race. As explained in the Monster Manual, goblinoid is a family of races. Goblin, bugbear, and hobgoblin are races.

Elves have subraces. Constructs are similar enough. Goblinoids are entirely different species with widely different forms who all worship Maglubiyet.

Comment: Jeremy Crawford's tweets are no longer canon. Do any other sources say this?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. As the other user mentioned, it would improve your answer to cite the relevant part of the *Monster Manual* that supports the claim made in the unofficial tweet.

Answer (score -1):

When you choose goblinoids as humanoid enemy, you include Goblins, Hobgoblins and Bugbears, all with one choice, no need to take each one separately.

Think about this, when you choose construct, do you choose only clay golems? When you choose dragons, are pseudodragons and true dragons sold individually sorted by color? When you choose elves, aren't high elves, drows and wild elves in the same package?

Choosing an humanoid, you pick 2 races, not 2 exemplars. You get goblinoids and dwarves or humans and elves and get the whole spectrum of the race.

Comment: The problem is that goblinoid isn't a race and goblin/hobgoblin/bugbear aren't subraces. They're distinct races that collaborate with each other closely.